# Printer Deployment via GPO - Login Time too long

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop-services, printer

our printers are configured as shared printers on a printserver.
They are deployed via GPO to different users/groups.

Currently the printer GPOs are set to "Remove this item whn it is no longer applied" to ensure, that old printers get removed automatically, after the user moves to another room. This setting forces the Printer into the "Replace" mode instead of "Update".
This has a big impact on the login time to our Terminalserver / Remote Desktop Server.
With the printers on "Update" the user logs in within a second, with the printers on "Replace" it can take up to a minute, depending on the user (it is stuck at Applying Group policy printers).

It has proven to work better than using a script which removes all the printers periodically before mapping them again via GPO.
Also we have a GPO to remove all shared printers which can be run after manually activating it, though I don't know a way to schedule it properly.

Do you have any suggestions how to achive having a clean printer deployment, without a bad impact on login time?

Comment: How many printers are configured ? Can you deploy the printers to the computer instead of the user ?

Comment: Up to 8 printers per GPO, in total we have about 40 printers installed.
I think this is not possible since the users work on a remote desktop server and on their PCs simultaneously in some cases.